# How to read HardDisk Temperature?

Tags: c#, hardware-interface

Is it possible to see the Harrdisk temperature with somekind of S.M.A.R.T API or anything like that?

i just want the temp, nothing else in C#

Comment: there isen't any problem.. i just need to find a S.M.A.R.T API - ive google'd but coulden't find any..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is code snippet from this [article](http://daran9.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/howto-get-harddisk-temperature-with-net/)
Hope it helps

```
//S.M.A.R.T.  Temperature attribute
const byte TEMPERATURE_ATTRIBUTE = 194;

public List<byte> GetDriveTemp()
{
    var retval = new List<byte>();
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
        //loop through all the hard disks
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            byte[] arrVendorSpecific = (byte[])queryObj.GetPropertyValue("VendorSpecific");
            //Find the temperature attribute
            int tempIndex = Array.IndexOf(arrVendorSpecific, TEMPERATURE_ATTRIBUTE);
            retval.Add(arrVendorSpecific[tempIndex + 5]);
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + err.Message);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: why is it tempIndex + 5, and i've posted a question about it already but do you know how to get the data from attribute 193 (load/unload cycle count)

Comment: Works fine, once you change  `List` to  `List<byte>`and include the reference to `System.Management`. Returns Celsius for local drives, 0 for a SSD.

Answer (score 2):

use VMI and `MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData` to get `VendorSpecific` byte array and 115 byte number is temperature. Why 115? More [here](http://vasters.com/clemensv/2011/04/11/Reading+ATAPI+SMART+Data+From+Drives+Using+NET+Temperature+Anyone.aspx).

Code partly generated with [VMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=8572)

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
"SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
   if (queryObj["VendorSpecific"] != null)
   {
       byte[] arrVendorSpecific = (byte[])(queryObj["VendorSpecific"]);
       string temp = arrVendorSpecific[115].ToString();
    }
 }
```