# Read External Hard Disk Temperature

Tags: c#, external, hard-drive, temp, temperature

I found the code for internal hard drives from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079613/1992635) but it doesn't seem to work with **external** ones, sorry, I'm not very experienced with S.M.A.R.T. Is there a way to find out the temp of an external drive through C#?

Comment: I'd rely on somehow calling smartmontools, which is the de-facto standard solution to read SMART values from any kind of devices and probably got the best coverage of different hardware.

Comment: Is the external ESATA or USB? If it is USB it is very likely you can't read the SMART data from it because SMART is part of the ATA protocol and USB devices don't use the SATA protocol.

Comment: It's USB, this is it: (http://www.toshiba.eu/hard-drives/portable/store-partner/), maybe it doesn't use SMART but with SpeedFan I can see its temp, so it's doable, but I don't know how..